# RSocketRequestor subscription is not getting cancelled even if the client is closed

Tags: flux, rsocket, spring-rsocket

When the client is closed, the rsocket server does not receive the cancellation event and ongoing flux subscription till continues.
How to cancel the ongoing subscription in server side when client is closed ?

Here is how I created the RSocketRequestor Bean in client side:
`rSocketRequesterBuilder .setupRoute("requests.registration") .setupData(clientId) .rsocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies) .rsocketConnector(connector -> connector.reconnect(retryBackoffSpec) .resume(new Resume().token( ()-> Unpooled.copiedBuffer(guid.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).retry(retryBackoffSpec))) .tcp("localhost", 8085)`